# proof of a homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, continuity

> I was wondering how to formalize the following proof that there exist disjoint nonempty homeomorphic sets $A$ and $B$ with $A\cup B= [0,1]$.

> **For the bounty, the following is what I'm looking for:**

- A formal definition of what the open and closed sets of $C$ and $D$ are. Are they just sets that may or may not include infinity and if so, why is that valid? With this definition, the proof should show that $g^{-1}(T)$ is open for every open set $T$ in $C$. From my understanding, it suffices to define open sets of a topological space $(X, \tau)$ as follows:
- The empty set and $X$ itself belong to $\tau$
- Any arbitrary (finite or infinite) union of members of $\tau$ belong to $\tau$
- The intersection of any finite number of members of $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$.
- A verification that the proof that $f$ is a homeomorphism is correct.

> 

One can define a homeomorphism $f$ between $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\pm \infty\}$ as follows:

$f(x)= \begin{cases} \tan(\pi (x-1/2)),&\text{ if $x\in (0,1)$}\\
-\infty, &\text{ if $x=0$}\\
\infty, &\text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$

To prove this is a homeomorphism, since $f$ is clearly bijective, it suffices to show that $f^{-1}(C)$ is open for every open set $C$ in $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\pm \infty\}$ (because $[0,1]$ is compact, it follows that $f^{-1}$ is continuous). The open sets of $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\pm \infty\}$ are precisely those sets of the form $(a,b), (a, \infty]$ and $[-\infty, b), [-\infty, \infty],  a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. On the other hand, the sets of the form $(a,b), [0,a), (b,1], [0,1], a,b \in [0,1]$ are all open in $[0,1]$ (and I think they are the only open sets, but I don't think it's necessary to prove this).

We have the following: $f^{-1}([-\infty, \infty]) = [0,1], f^{-1}((a,b)) = (\frac{1}\pi \arctan(a) + 1/2, \frac{1}\pi \arctan(b) + 1/2), f^{-1}((a, \infty]) = (\frac{1}\pi \arctan(a) + 1/2, 1], f^{-1} ([-\infty, b)) = [0, \frac{1}\pi \arctan(b) + 1/2).$

Now partition $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\pm \infty\}$ into the disjoint nonempty sets $C = \cup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} [2k, 2k+1) \cup \{\infty\}$ and $D = \cup_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} [-2k - 1, -2k )\cup \{-\infty\}$. First, suppose for a contradiction that $x\in [2k, 2k+1) \cap [-2l-1, -2l)$ for some $l \in \mathbb{Z}, 2k \leq x < 2k + 1$ and $-2l-1 \leq x < -2l,$ so $-2l - 1 < 2k + 1$ and $2k  < -2l$. This implies $-2(l+k) < 2\Rightarrow l + k > -1.$ We also have $k < -l$ so $l+k < 0$. This contradicts the fact that both $l$ and $k$ are integers. Now let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. We want to show that it lies in either $C$ or $D$. Either there exists $k$ so that $2k \leq x < 2k+1$ or there exists an integer $k$ so that $2k - 1 \leq x < 2k$, from which the result follows.

We claim that the map $g : C\to D$ which sends $\infty$ to $-\infty$ and $[2k, 2k+1)$ homeomorphically to $[-2k-1, -2k)$ by mapping $x$ to $-x$ for $x\in (2k, 2k+1)$ and mapping $2k$ to $-2k-1$ is a homeomorphism.

> The problem is, I'm not sure how to show this; it's also possible $g$ isn't a homeomorphism. It is a bijection, with inverse given by $g^{-1}(-\infty) = \infty, g^{-1}(x) = -x$ for $x\in (-2k-1, -2k), g^{-1}(-2k-1) = 2k$.

> If $g$ is a homeomorphism, I should be able to show that $g^{-1} (C)$ is open for every open subset of $C$, but I'm not sure how to show this.

Finally, note that we can take $A =  f^{-1} (C)$ and $B = f^{-1}(D)$ as the required sets, because $f^{-1} \circ g \circ f$ is a homeomorphism from $A$ to $B$ and clearly $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and nonempty.

Comment: to show continuity of $g$, it suffices to show that’s it’s continuous on an interval $[2k, 2k+1)$, which seems obvious. similarly with $g^{-1}$.

Comment: @CSquared yeah it's obvious to show continuity on an interval. My issue is that I don't really understand what continuity even means when working with extended real numbers. What would be the open sets in $C$ and $D$ for instance?

Answer (score 1):

Claim: The map $g : C\to D$ which sends $\infty$ to $-\infty$ and $[2k, 2k+1)$ homeomorphically to $[-2k-1, -2k)$ by mapping $x$ to $-x$ for $x\in (2k, 2k+1)$ and mapping $2k$ to $-2k-1$ is a homeomorphism.

> Below is the proof of the above claim, which is the main claim that would complete the proof in the question.

Clearly, $g^{-1} : D\to C$ satisfies $g^{-1}(-\infty) = \infty, g^{-1}(x) = -x$ for $x\in (-2k-1, -2k), g^{-1}(-2k-1) = 2k.$

Let $C' = C\backslash \{\infty\}, D' = D\backslash \{-\infty\}$.

The idea is to show that for every open set in $C'$, it is a union of intervals of the form $(a, b), [2k, a)$ for some $k, a < b \in (2k, 2k+1)$.

Every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a (countable) union of open intervals, and so for any open set $A$ in $C', A = O\cap C'$ for some open set $O = \cup_{s\in S}I_s, S$ is some countable set and each $I_s$ is an open interval, in $\mathbb{R}$, and so $A = \cup_{s\in S} I_s \cap C'$. So every open set in $C'$ is a union of sets of the form $I_s \cap C'$, where $I_s$ is an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$. Fix an $s\in S$ and suppose $I_s\cap C'\neq \emptyset$. Let $I_s = (a,b)$. Let $a_1$ be the smallest even integer that's greater than $a$ and let $b_1$ be the largest even integer that's less than $b$. Suppose first that $I_s$ contains an even integer $2k.$ Observe that $a_1 \leq b_1$ as $a_1 \leq 2k\leq b_1$ where $2k \in (a,b)$. Then observe that $ I_s\cap C' = (a, a_1 - 1)\cup  \cup_{k = a_1/2}^{b_1/2} [2k, \max\{b,2k+1\}) =: U.$ Indeed, clearly $I_s\cap C'\subseteq U$ because if $\exists x \in I_s\cap C'\backslash U$, then $x$ must lie in $[2t-1, 2t)$ for some integer $t$, but that is a contradiction as $x\in C'$. Also, $U\subseteq C'$ clearly and $U\subseteq I_s$ because all elements fall within the range $(a,b)$. Now suppose $I_s$ does not contain any even integers. Note that $a_1 = b_1 + 2$. $a_1$ must be greater than or equal to $b$, or else it would be in $I_s$ and similarly $b_1$ must be at most $a$. We can find an even integer $2c,2c+2$ with $2c \leq b\leq 2c+2$. Then $a\ge 2c$ and so $a_1 = 2c + 2, b_1 = 2c, I_s\subseteq [2c, 2c+2)$. Then $I_s\cap C' = (a, a_1+1)$, which is of the required form.

Thus since each $I_s\cap C'$ can be written in the required form, every open set $C'$ can be written in the required form.

Similarly, the open sets in $D'$ are unions of intervals of the form $(a,b), [2k - 1, a)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}, a < b\in (2k-1, 2k)$. Note that to show $g$ is continuous, it suffices to show that $g^{-1}(X)$ is open for each open $X\in D' $ because if $Y$ is an open set in $D$, then $Y\backslash \{-\infty\} = \cup_{s\in S} I_s$ where for each $s\in S, I_s$ is of the form described above. So $g^{-1}(Y\backslash \{-\infty\}) = \cup_{s\in S} g^{-1}(I_s)$, which equals $g^{-1}(Y)$ and is open in $C$ if $Y$ does not contain $-\infty$. If $Y$ does contain $-\infty$, then $g^{-1}(Y) = \cup_{s\in S} (g^{-1}(I_s)\cup \{-\infty\})$ and each $g^{-1}(I_s)\cup \{-\infty\}$ is open as each set $g^{-1}(I_s)$ is open in $C'$.

Since the claim holds, it suffices to show that for each $k \in \mathbb{Z}, a < b\in (2k - 1, 2k),$ both $ g^{-1}((a,b))$ and $g^{-1} ([2k - 1, a))$ are open in $C$. So fix $k \in \mathbb{Z}, a < b\in (2k - 1, 2k).$ Then $g^{-1}((a,b)) = (-b,-a),$ which is open in $C$. Also, $g^{-1}([2k-1, a)) = [-2k, a),$ which is open in $C$. So $g$ is continuous. Similarly, one can show that $g^{-1}$ is continuous. Indeed, for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}, a < b \in (2k, 2k+1), g((a,b)) = (-b,-a), g([2k, a)) = [-2k-1, a).$ Thus, $g$ is a homeomorphism, as required.